# How can I improve this multiple join monster query?

Tags: mysql

For your sakes i'm not gonna paste it all here, just know that it's hella long and involves a lot of joins.

The table structure i'm working on, at its most complicated, looks like this:

```
tables = Co, Cn, O, A, N;
scheme (simplified):
N(n)-> (1)every other table
A(n)-> (1)(every other table except N
O(n)-> (1)Co, Cn
Cn(n) -> (1)Co
Co(1) -> (1)cn
```

The most laborious part of the query goes trough the structure like this (i'm trying to get information from table N but also from the other ones):

```
N join A join O join ((Co join Cn) union (Cn join Co ))
```

I need to get the contents from N but I also need stuff from Co and Cn but I must go trough A and O to get them. Now, this may not seem like a huge query but N can also relate to every one of those other tables and I need to get them ALL; let's just say I can't see the content from the query if I echo it in the aplication. I join each case separately (N->A, N->O, N->Cn, etc) and then grab them all up with a UNION

At the moment, with almost 200,000 lines in N and a couple hundred to almost a thousand in each of the other tables the database server and the website just hangs when I try to run the query.

One solution I thought of was to ditch the foreign keys and make a field for links that goes, for an example from N trough all the others: "A_IdA,O_IdO,Co_IdCo,Cn_IdCn", and process it in php; but I'd rather try something else before such a drastic change in table design.

Comment: What are the exact relationships between the tables? For example, between `N` and `A`, is it `1:1`, `1:n` or `n:1` ?

Comment: The actual select statement would make things much clearer. Surely the select statement for 6 joins cannot be **that** long.

Comment: I'll try to clarify the situation a bit.

Comment: I'll also post the entire query in the morning as I can't get it at home. I'll work on formatting it a bit.

Comment: I'm now curious of the database design. Too many relationships you seem to have, not a very common approach. The query, especially the `FROM` part will clarify many things I think, too.

Comment: If you're worried about posting a giant block of text, try putting it on pastebin, and just pasting a link here.

Answer (score 0):

I'm having a hard time trying to grasp your exact table structure and query.

However, I feel like you're trying to combine too much into 1 query, causing the joining to be extremely stressful on the DB server. You'd most likely be better of performing multiple simpler queries, then trying to do it all in 1 huge query.

Comment: Yes I thought of that but I need the result to be in a single table for the final output. Otherwise we'll need to change the core structure of our code and It'll cease to be backwards compatible.